# Why is Facebook Android sdk a Project?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

Anyone knows why is Facebook for Android SDK distributed as a Library Project instead of a jar?

I know you "can" compile it as a jar and everything, just wondering if there is any advantage on distribute it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary reason why the Facebook SDK is distributed as a Library Project is probably because it contains resources. This is the most straightforward way to distribute this kind of thing with resources. You can't simply compile it as a jar file.

Comment: Yup, common complaint in android. The only way to share libraries that contain resources is in the form of library projects...

Comment: Indeed, it used to be possible to package it as a .jar until resources were recently added to the project.

Comment: Fairly recently Google has introduced the .aar library format to address this, as part of their new build system. Hopefully Facebook will eventually package their SDK this way: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

Answer (score 0):

One advantage is that you can make modifications to the source if you need to. The Facebook SDK is known to be buggy and a real pain to use in general. The ability to fix stuff is incredibly helpful, and it also gives you the option to create pull requests to their project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Because doing so will not give the access of library project's resources to dependent projects.